# google cloud and key managment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identityserver4

I'm working with identityServer4 and trying to use the method .AddSigningCredential().

I want to use google cloud key ring management for encryption.

I found this link, and it describes what I think I want to do, but I can't figure out how to do it with google cloud.

https://brockallen.com/2019/08/09/identityserver-and-signing-key-rotation/

If this doesn't work or isn't possible I have an ssl cert saved on google cloud used by the load balancer, I think I could pull that into this method but can't find examples on how to do that either.

Comment: Can you describe what do you want to achieve and what are your pain points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Platform encrypts data stored at rest by default, with no action required from you.

Cloud KMS is a cloud-hosted key management service that lets you manage encryption for your cloud services the same way you do on-premises. With Cloud KMS you can [create](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/creating-keys), [rotate](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/rotating-keys), automatically rotate and [destroy](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/destroy-restore) symmetric encryption keys (I understand this is what you want to do).

You can generate, use, rotate, and destroy AES256, RSA 2048, RSA 3072, RSA 4096, EC P256, and EC P384 keys.

Cloud KMS allows you to [import](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/importing-a-key#key_import_flow) user-provided cryptographic keys.

*For security reasons, the raw cryptographic key material represented by a Cloud KMS key can never be viewed or exported. It can only be used by an authorized user to encrypt or decrypt data when they invoke the Cloud KMS API

> > I have an ssl cert saved on google cloud used by the load balancer.

Is this a Google-managed or self-managed certificate?